# Use external files in NETPLAN

Tags: networking, netplan

Is it possible to load an external file in one of NETPLAN's yaml configurations files?

Similar to "source" in interfaces?

My situation:

I have an application that controls the network configurations, because i don't want the user interacting with the OS, but i don't want the application to run as root either.

So in earlier versions, i just added "source" to interfaces pointing to the file my application creates.
Is it possible to have the same behaviour with NETPLAN? or do i really have to add my file to /etc/netplan/?

Comment: @user535733 correction: it'll load all YAML files in /etc/netplan.  If someone is trying to include external files in a netplan config it won't work right.

Comment: I don't think the YAML spec has any functionality for including additional files into the configuration for replacement/etc Luis.  In which case the answer is "there is no way to get the same behavior" without some intermediate script which will generate the netplan configurations *based* on the data in the 'source' file you're referring to.